# Display Message on success Using Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

On the success function of jquery ajax request i am displaying a message in `span` tag.

```
success: function(data) {
       if(data = true) {
          $("#result").text("is available"); 
       }else {
          $("#result").text("is not available"); 
       }
});
```

When data is true then `"is available` is display which is ok but when data is false then still it display `"is available` instead of `"is not available`.

Answer (score 1):

`data = true` needs to be `data === 'true'`.

`data = true` attempts to set the value of `data` to the Boolean `true`. `data === 'true'` compares `data` to the string `'true'`.

---

For more info on JS comparison operators, see [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison_operators).

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning data to true, do

```
data == true
```

Answer (score 0):

You just want to test if data exists. Use the following

```
success: function(data) {
       if(data) {
          $("#result").text("is available"); 
       }else {
          $("#result").text("is not available"); 
       }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried comparing with 'true' like @Mooseman suggests below?